# How to ignore target folder in TortoiseSVN

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, svnignore

How can I ignore the target folder in TortoiseSVN?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I Assume that you have already set up a Subversion repository and you want to ignore a folder called "target" in your working copy.

Right click on the target folder icon, choose "TortoiseSVN -> Add to ignore list -> target";
Right click on the icon of the folder containing target and choose "SVN Commit...";
Enter a message text and press OK.

Answer (score 8):

This is an old question but for further reference: It can also be globally configured in the "TortoiseSVN"->"Settings" contextual menu option. Just add "target" (separated with a space) to the "Global ignore pattern" setting and click "Apply"

[image]

Comment: nice, ignored bin obj *.user .vs for all of my c# projects